# Is there a nice way to represent $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{n+1}H_n}{n+m+1}$?

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, definite-integrals, harmonic-numbers, polylogarithm

Here, $H_n$ denotes the [harmonic number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number#:%7E:text=In%20mathematics%2C%20the%20n%2Dth,the%20first%20n%20positive%20integers.). More colloquially, is there any way to represent $$\int_0^1 x^{n-1}\log^2\left(1+x\right)\ \mathrm{d}x$$ in a nice way? The latter is corollary to the original question; namely,
$$\int_0^1 x^{n-1}\log^2\left(1+x\right)\ \mathrm{d}x = \frac{\log^2(2)}{n}-\frac{2}{n}\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^{k+1}H_{\ell}}{n+k+1}...$$
which I do not know how to simplify. Thank you!

Comment: Mathematica gives a closed expression for the integral form $$s(m) = i(m) =\int_0^1 \frac{x^m \log (x+1)}{x+1} \, dx =\left( \frac{2^m \log (2) \, _2F_1\left(-m,-m;1-m;\frac{1}{2}\right)}{m}-\frac{2^m \, _3F_2\left(-m,-m,-m;1-m,1-m;\frac{1}{2}\right)}{m^2}+\pi  \csc (\pi  m) (\psi ^{(0)}(-m)+\gamma )\right)$$.    This expression is, however, far from "nice" because it diverges at integers $m \ge 0$ and has to be understood as a limit to integers.

Comment: Very _nice_. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

*Mathematica* choked when I gave it the general expression (at least the way I tried).  Here's how the sum works out for some small values of $m$.

\begin{gather}
m = 0 : \tfrac{1}{2}\log^2(2) \\
m = 1 : -1 + 2 \log(2) - \tfrac{1}{2}\log^2(2) \\
m = 2 : \tfrac{5}{4} - 2 \log(2) + \tfrac{1}{2}\log^2(2)   \\
m = 3 : - \tfrac{55}{36} + \tfrac{8}{3} \log(2) - \tfrac{1}{2}\log^2(2)  \\
m = 4 : \tfrac{241}{144} -\tfrac{8}{3} \log(2)-\tfrac{1}{2}\log^2(2)  \\
m = 5 : - \tfrac{6589}{3600} + \tfrac{46}{15} \log(2) + \tfrac{1}{2}\log^2(2) 
\end{gather}

Comment: The rational numbers appearig here can be found in OEIS.org,  except for the numerators of the term without $\log$, i.e. the sequence (-1,5,-55,241,-6589, ...)